# Dynamically resize widget's when resizing a window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to dynamically resize a widget's size while resizing a window in tkinter ?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("777x575")

text = Text(root , width = 75 , height = 25)
text.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root , command = text.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0 , column = 1 , sticky = N+S+E+W)

text.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)

button = Button(root , text = "Sample Button")
button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 20)

mainloop()
```

when I resize my window, the width and height of the widgets stay the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6aro.png).

what I want is to dynamically resize the widget's inside my window according to the window's size.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter ?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: `Grid.rowconfigure(root, (0,1), weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, (0,1), weight=1)
`

Comment: It only moves the widgets, but is there any way to resize them dynamically?

Comment: Apply `sticky='nsew'` to all the widgets

Comment: The width of the button changes to the width of the whole window. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: remove `sticky='nsew'` only for the button widget.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Here's exactly what I want. Assume I have a window with dimension 200x200 and I have a button with dimension 100x50. Now when I resize my window to 400x400 , I want the button to change it's dimension to 200x100. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can, for that, you might have to bind the root widget to the `<Configure>` event and change the width and height manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this raw source code example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("777x575")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

text = Text(root, width = 95 , height = 95)
text.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=500, ipady=10, sticky="NSEW")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

button = Button(root, text = "Sample Button")
button.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=500, ipady=10, sticky="NSEW")

mainloop()
```